# Extract inconsistence format PDF data into excel

Tags: pdf, power-automate

I am need to build an AI model to extract data in the PDF into excel. I can use Power automate AI builder, but the issue is all the Pdfs are in different formats. There are more than 5k Pdfs
I have tried power automate Ai Builder but failed to extract the required data.
Please could you suggest the best way I could build something automate for long term usage.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What do the PDF’s represent? e.g. are they invoices?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a document processing custom model with unstructured documents and see if you have a better result ?

You can also post our message to the Power Automate Community
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/AI-Builder/bd-p/AIBuilder

Hope it helps!

Comment: As this post may answer the question, you're asking a direct question which otherwise should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use something like this GPT template flow to extract data from any PDF without training different models: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Extract-Data-From-PDFs-and-Images-With-GPT/td-p/2201345